# Прокрутка вниз в iframe

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, html, iframe

Здравствуйте, у меня появился вопрос:
я делаю чатик и `iframe`'ом вывожу его содержимое, все бы хорошо но когда сообщений много, появляются скролы прокрутки и вниз не уходят, вот обращаюсь за помощью.

Как можно реализовать, чтобы когда появлялось новое сообщение, скрол уходил вниз, либо через определенное время? Только одно но: не обновляя страницу. Сообщения выводятся через AJAX и если обновлять, они теряются.

Спасибо за помощь и уделенное мне время :)

Comment: @Manitikyl, вы где-нибуть сохраняете сообщения (БД, текстовый файл etc.)?

Comment: нет) они через COMET выводятся клиентам :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@Manitikyl](/users/3967/manitikyl)](/users/3967/manitikyl), с Comet знаком поверхностно, поэтому сложно что-то посоветовать. Если будет интересно, то вот две статьи по вашему вопросу - [Часть 1](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=757), [Часть 2](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=758). Стараюсь не ссылаться на сайт Попова, т.к. органически его не переношу, но тут всего лишь перевод [оригинальной статьи](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/10/ajax-web-chat-css-jquery/). Полностью всё принимать ко вниманию, вам там не особо нужно. Посмотрите ту часть, которая отвечает за прокрутку. Откройте "[Демо](http://ruseller.com/lessons/les757/demo/index.html)" в двух браузерах, напишите сообщение (может несколько, дабы заполнить окно чата) в одном из них и смотрите результат работы в другом.

P.S. И Боже упаси, чтоб посетив указанный мной сайт, вы клюнули на уроки Попова! )) Почитали статьи и удалили сайт из истории, очистив кэш и повым с мылом руки ;)

А вообще, на мой взгляд, самое умное решение это **WebSockets** - надстройка над HTTP-протоколом, поддерживающая длительное соединение. Только вот незадачка... поддерживается не всеми браузерами. Почитать о **WebSockets** можно [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/79038/).

Answer (score 1):

```
function scrollMessage(msgBox){
    window.scrollBy(0, $(msgBox).height());
}
```

`msgBox` - элемент с сообщением, выведенным на экран.